# react native stepcounter API for calculating the steps?

Tags: android, react-native

I am developing an fitness app in Android using react native.
Is there any stepcounter/pedometer APIs through which I can calculate the steps?
I have gone through the npm packages but stepcounter/pedometer is available for iOS only not for Android

I've found a pedometer with Expo but I'm concentrating only on react native pedometers which support Android not only iOS

can you please help me out to suggest whether there are any pedometers/stepcounter APIs?

Thank you

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-develop-a-simple-step-counter-app-on-reactn 
this may help you